# How do you track sql queries in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We are in the process of upgrading to Oracle 12c and I need to track the queries being executed by the application.  In other words if the application executes a query like select 'foobar' from dual; I would like see the text "select 'foobar' from dual" in the output file.

If I follow the instructions here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL809 I get files that contain statistics like the following but not the actual sql queries.

```
WAIT #0: nam='rdbms ipc message' ela= 2999770 timeout=300 p2=0 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=1103506389
WAIT #0: nam='rdbms ipc message' ela= 9854 timeout=1 p2=0 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=1103522400

*** 2016-04-07 15:07:20.715
WAIT #0: nam='rdbms ipc message' ela= 2999585 timeout=300 p2=0 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=1106522506
WAIT #0: nam='rdbms ipc message' ela= 9690 timeout=1 p2=0 p3=0 obj#=-1 tim=1106532500
```

If I look for the query like this I get 0 results: grep -rnw "foobar" --include=*.trc ./

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... e.g. Are you after how often those queries are executed, what queries are executed from the application, what the wait times are, what the run times are, what the execution plans are, etc, etc...but, depending on what you are after, you may be able to get what you need from the following views: v$active_session_history, v$sql, and v$sql_plan

Comment: The use case here is: I would like to see every single query issued to the database.

Comment: Then you can certainly get that information from select * from v$active_session_history ash, v$sql sql where sql.sql_id = ash.sql_id order by sample_time desc;  Be advised that ASH only maintains information for several hours, but you could periodically dump the queries to a history table if you need to better retention.

Answer (score 0):

One option is looking up the AWR repositories for it. It will keep a few days worth of SQLs. There's plenty of additional information in the system views, so this is strictly the text, but feel free to explore.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, to_char(substr(h.sql_text, 1, 4000)) sqltxt
  FROM dba_hist_sqltext h
  JOIN dba_hist_active_sess_history a ON a.sql_id = h.sql_id
  JOIN dba_users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
 WHERE username = 'SYS';
```

I filtered the results for SYS just as an example, but you can change it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see all the activity the best thing you should do is have an EM (Enterprise Manager) set for you.

If you don't, gv$activity_session_history would be a good call, it's better seen when using grouping functions. Simply selecting on it would be a mess depending on the number of calls your application is pushing.

Another way, you could see it in an average manner:

```
`
select s.parsing_schema_name,
             inst_id,
             sql_id,
             plan_hash_value,
             child_number,
             round(nullif(s.ELAPSED_TIME, 0) / nullif(s.EXECUTIONS, 0) / 1000000, 4) elap_per_exec,
       round(s.USER_IO_WAIT_TIME / nullif(s.ELAPSED_TIME, 0) * 100, 2) io_wait_pct,
       round(s.CLUSTER_WAIT_TIME / nullif(s.ELAPSED_TIME, 0) * 100, 2) cluster_wait_pct,
       round(s.application_wait_time / nullif(s.ELAPSED_TIME, 0) * 100, 2) app_wait_pct,
       round(s.CPU_TIME / nullif(s.ELAPSED_TIME, 0) * 100, 2) cpu_time_pct,
       round(s.PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES / nullif(s.EXECUTIONS, 0) / 1024 / 1024, 2) pio_per_exec_mb,
       round(s.PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES / nullif(s.PHYSICAL_READ_REQUESTS, 0), 2) / 1024 read_per_request_kbytes,
             round(s.buffer_gets /  nullif(s.executions, 0), 4) BufferGets_per_Exec
             s.executions,
             to_char(s.last_active_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') last_act_time,
             s.first_load_time,
             s.sql_fulltext,             
             s.sql_profile,
             s.sql_patch,
             s.sql_plan_baseline
FROM   gv$sql s
WHERE  1=1
and    s.parsing_schema_name in ('LIST OF DATABASE USERS YOU WANT TO MONITOR')
order  by s.last_active_time desc;  
`
```

It would give a good perspective of how well your doing based in your average thresholds.